# how can i see the profile field on registration page?

Tags: php, drupal-6, user-registration

I have made customized user registration page. and i have made that on theme layer.
But now i want to see the the fields which i have made in profile module.
as i have written like this for

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['account']['name']); ?>
```

this code will show the user name field. which is default. now i want to see the profile fields which i have created on the profile module.
 **So can any one tell me what i have to write in drupal_render[?]?** 

Thanks in advance.

---

Nitish
[Panchjanya Corporation](http://www.panchjanyacorp.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using Drupal 6, you might want to know that you can just choose a checkbox, *Appear in Registration page* which shows up when you are creating a new user profile field from the Admin UI.

Else you can try this.

```
$categories = profile_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) {
  $result = _profile_get_fields($category['name']);
  # You can add code here to render each category seperately #
  while($field = db_result($result)) {
    $fieldname = $field['name'];
    drupal_render($form[$category][$fieldname]);
  }
}
```

Comment: do i have to change any thing in this code?...bcz its giving me warning like  "Illegal offset"... when i have copied same code on my tpl file. i know about that checkbox but i want to create some good looking form so thats why i am making own customized....

Comment: No no. This is not to be added to the tpl file but to the code (your own module preferably).